# Sudden Weird Eclipse Behaviour

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

My eclipse has started displaying weird debug behavior. Whenever I set a break point the compiler breaks at that particular statement which is normal , now the weird part starts when I press F8 to go to the next statement , the compiler doesn't break and stop at the next statement instead it executes the entire program as if I selected resume. Is there any way i could fix that ?

Answer (score 4):

That's because F8 is resume. The keyboard shortcut for next statement is F6.

Answer (score 0):

F5: Step in (go inside a method call)
F6: Step over (go to next statement - this is what you want)
F7: Step out (leave a method call)
F8: Resume (will stop at next breakpoint - this is what you are doing)

Source: http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html#link_11